# Arguments for and against necessetarianism

Tags: reference-request, necessity

I would like to read some texts that argue for/against necessitarianism, meaning, the belief that the world can't be otherwise. I am one such person who believes that, and I would like to hear of the arguments both for and against that position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are theoretically infinite ways the world could be, but according to necessitarianism only this one was possible.

By which method this one was singled out of infinite possibilities? Did someone deliberately design this universe and all the events that will ever happen? Or was it a completely random occurrence?

The problem with necessitarianism and determinism is that they completely ignore the question of origin. Why exactly this happens instead of something else? That is why both are invalid philosophical standpoints, they don't *explain* anything, they just *assume*.

If a universe cannot evolve randomly without any control and it cannot be deliberately designed either, no universe can exist. A deck of cards can be ordered in myriad ways, either deliberately or randomly shuffled. There is no "necessary" order.